# RSA: Show how to factor $n=pq$, the product of two primes, given $(p-1)(q-1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, cryptography

As an exercise in my discrete mathematics textbook, for my first-year course, the following question is asked, on the topic of RSA encryption:
Show that we can easily factor $n$ when we know that $n$ is the product of two primes, $p$ and $q$, and we know the value of $(p-1)(q-1)$.

So far my attempted solution has been to expand $(p-1)(q-1)$, to lay a foundation of the known value.
$$(p-1)(q-1)=pq-p-q+1$$
and rewrite
$$(p-1)(q-1)=pq-(p+q)+1$$
The book suggests calling $p+q=s$
and then attempting to use that to find the product $n$, since $q=s-p$, we can write the product as $n=p(s-p)$. Expanding this leads to the quadratic equation
$$0=p^2-ps+n$$
Using the quadratic formula to solve this leads to the following solution:
$$p=\frac{s\pm\sqrt{s^2-4n}}{2}$$
As shown by @misterriemann in the comments, the discriminant can not be negative, which leaves out any complex solutions, however i am unsure how to extract $q$ from this, after being given $p$ as a function of $s$.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: The discriminant cannot be negative, since by [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), $$ \frac{p+q}{2} \geq \sqrt{pq}, $$ and so $$ s^2 = (p+q)^2 \geq 4pq = 4n.  $$

Comment: ^That's an answer.

Comment: Ah of course, thank you. I will revise my original question, and refer to this.

Comment: _"i have no idea how to extract q from this, after being given p as a function of s_" .You already know that $q=s-p$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The discriminant cannot be negative, since by [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), $$ \frac{p+q}{2} \geq \sqrt{pq}, $$ and so $$ s^2 = (p+q)^2 \geq 4pq = 4n \quad \Rightarrow \quad   s^2-4n \geq 0.$$

Furthermore, since you know the value of $(p-1)(q-1),$ (as well as $n=pq)$, you also know $s$, since
$$ s = p+q = pq-(p-1)(q-1)+1. $$

Then you can find $p$ from your formula, which immediately gives you $q$ as well, since
$$ p+q=s \quad \iff \quad q=s-p, $$
or if you prefer to do division,
$$ n=pq \quad \iff \quad q = \frac{n}{p}. $$

Comment: Your third equation made me realize that i totally missed a solution for s, given in terms of "known" values. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: You're very welcome!